# javascript canceled request after 50 seconds

Tags: javascript, java, performance, frontend, wildfly

Describing of context: java app (running under wildfly) works under high workload and heap is almost filled. Because of that full GC runs often and this leads to frequent long Stop The World phases.

While these phases I try to make login request.
So, if I make this request via front-end side (I just open login page, fill fields and click login button) I see this:
[image]

It is interesting that I get canceled request ALWAYS after 50 seconds and front-end even canot make tcp handhaske.

But if I make the same direct request just using console devtools of chrome (alternative is using postman, for example), I see this:
[image]

In that case browser establish tcp handshake, send reqiest and wait 2,6 mint for first byte from the server etc,.

Why I see that difference behavioral ? What is root cause of that ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been investigating similar issue, where something killed the request between BE and FE after exactly 50 seconds and I ran into this question. So I am posting here in case it helps someone in future.

In our case, it was the k8s Openstack loadbalancer timeout that did not wait for backend's response:
https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/configuration/configref.html
Specifically `timeout_client_data` and `timeout_member_data`.

We updated the IstioOperator settings in `spec.components.ingressGateways.k8s.serviceAnnotations` with following annotations:

```
loadbalancer.openstack.org/timeout-client-data: "180000"
loadbalancer.openstack.org/timeout-member-data: "180000"
```

to increase the timeout limit and then we were able to receive response successfully.

You can find more details on loadbalancer annotation possibilities here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/blob/master/docs/openstack-cloud-controller-manager/expose-applications-using-loadbalancer-type-service.md